SQL Key propagation query
I have a SQL Server table structured as follows: RowNumber, Level, PartNumber, ProductNumber and Key.
I need to propagate the Key value (when it is not NULL) from a row to all subsequent rows with a higher level (greater than the current row's level) until it encounters a row with a level that is equal to or less than the starting row's level (see the points below).



RowNumber
Level
PartNumber
ProductNumber
Key




1
0
099
A
NULL


2
1
001
A
NULL


3
2
012
A
012_A


4
3
003
A
NULL


5
4
094
A
094_A


6
4
005
A
NULL


7
3
006
A
006_A


8
2
007
A
007_A


9
2
008
A
NULL


10
3
009
A
NULL


11
3
010
A
010_A


12
4
011
A
NULL


13
2
012
A
NULL



What I expect:

This problem is a parent-child structure (lower level acts as parent and higher levels as child).

In the example, line 3 is a level 2 part and there are parts below that row with levels 3 and 4, they belong to the part in line 3.

Therefore, the key in line 3 must be propagated from there to the row 7, even if the parts in that range have a key.

Line 8 is another level 2, but there is no higher level below it, so the key remains in row 8.

Line 11, part is level 3 and there is a part below level 4, the key must be propagated in row 12.

If there was a key in line 2 (for example), all the lines below would receive that key, because levels 2, 3 and 4 belong to 1.





RowNumber
Level
PartNumber
ProductNumber
Key




1
0
099
A
NULL


2
1
001
A
NULL


3
2
012
A
012_A


4
3
003
A
012_A


5
4
094
A
012_A


6
4
005
A
012_A


7
3
006
A
012_A


8
2
007
A
007_A


9
2
008
A
NULL


10
3
009
A
NULL


11
3
010
A
010_A


12
4
011
A
010_A


13
2
012
A
NULL



The code below didn't get exactly what I expected, for example, on line 10 it propagated the key from line 8  (but the part number from line 10 belongs to line 9, not 8. Then should not propagate from 8 to 10). I would appreciate it if someone could guide me on what I could try differently, a better approach. Thanks!
 SELECT
        C1.[RowNumber],
        C1.[Level], 
        C1.[PartNumber],
        C1.[ProductNumber],
        COALESCE(
            C1.[Key],
            (SELECT TOP 1 C2.[Key]
             FROM TableName C2 
             WHERE C2.[Level] < C1.[Level]
               AND C2.[RowNumber] < C1.[RowNumber]
               AND C2.[Key] IS NOT NULL
             ORDER BY C2.[Level] DESC, C2.[RowNumber] DESC
            )
        ) AS [Key]
FROM 
        TableName C1


What is the Index column?

If Index=RowNumber then this fiddle might help us collaborate on a solution https://dbfiddle.uk/wf6RpRB0

Hi, is the line/row number. I changed it to make more sense.

Row 7 looks wrong in your expected outcome compared to the question..

Thanks for pointing it out, I'll elaborate further. Look at this problem as a parent-child structure, lines 7 and 4 (level 3) belong to line 3 (level 2), they should receive the key from line 3 even if they have one. And lines 5 and 6 (level 4) belong to 4, and the same, they belong to 3 (that's why lines 4 to 7 receive the same key as 3).

It seems you have to do this row by row using CTE:
SELECT  *
INTO #data
FROM    (
    VALUES  (1, 0, N'099', N'A', NULL)
    ,   (2, 1, N'001', N'A', NULL)
    ,   (3, 2, N'012', N'A', N'012_A')
    ,   (4, 3, N'003', N'A', NULL)
    ,   (5, 4, N'094', N'A', N'094_A')
    ,   (6, 4, N'005', N'A', NULL)
    ,   (7, 3, N'006', N'A', N'006_A')
    ,   (8, 2, N'007', N'A', N'007_A')
    ,   (9, 2, N'008', N'A', NULL)
    ,   (10, 3, N'009', N'A', NULL)
    ,   (11, 3, N'010', N'A', N'010_A')
    ,   (12, 4, N'011', N'A', NULL)
    ,   (13, 2, N'012', N'A', NULL)
) t (RowNumber,Level,PartNumber,ProductNumber,[Key])

;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT  RowNumber, Level, Level AS MasterLevel, PartNumber, ProductNumber
    ,   [key]
    FROM    #data
    WHERE   RowNumber = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  d.RowNumber, d.Level
    ,   CASE WHEN master.flag = 1 THEN c.MasterLevel ELSE d.Level END
    ,   d.PartNumber, d.ProductNumber
    ,   CASE WHEN master.flag = 1 THEN c.[Key] ELSE d.[Key] END
    FROM    cte c
    INNER JOIN #data d
        ON  d.rowNumber = c.RowNumber + 1
    CROSS APPLY (
            SELECT  CASE WHEN c.MasterLevel < d.Level AND c.[key] IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS flag
        ) master
    )
SELECT  *
FROM    cte

I introduce a MasterLevel column which holds current level from which the keys are copied. This is either taken from previous row or current if current row level is less or equals to master level.
Then based on the MasterLevel and key, i add a flag which says if a key copy should occur or not, and create the values appropriately.
Output:



RowNumber
Level
MasterLevel
PartNumber
ProductNumber
key




1
0
0
099
A
NULL


2
1
1
001
A
NULL


3
2
2
012
A
012_A


4
3
2
003
A
012_A


5
4
2
094
A
012_A


6
4
2
005
A
012_A


7
3
2
006
A
012_A


8
2
2
007
A
007_A


9
2
2
008
A
NULL


10
3
3
009
A
NULL


11
3
3
010
A
010_A


12
4
3
011
A
010_A


13
2
2
012
A
NULL



Btw, this structure you're using ain't standard, normally one uses concrete IDs to figure out child/parent relations, which does away the need of doing this level-walk.

I wonder if productnumber has an impact that isn't brought out in the sample data.

Can use a CTE with recursion. With the starting table make a subset that is only rows where KEY <> NULL. Use recursion with this subset to get the previous row's KEY, only when LEVEL has increased, and only when NULL appears. This gives you a final subset that you use to populate the rows in the original table.

WITH cte_recursion AS(
    SELECT
        RowNumber,
        [Level],
        PartNumber,
        ProductNumber,
        [Key]
    FROM source_table
    WHERE [Key] IS NOT NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        C2.RowNumber,
        C2.[Level],
        C2.PartNumber,
        C2.ProductNumber,
        CTE.[Key]
    FROM cte_recursion CTE
    JOIN source_table C2
      ON C2.RowNumber = CTE.RowNumber + 1
     AND C2.[Level] > CTE.[Level] 
     AND C2.[Key] IS NULL         
  )

SELECT
    T.RowNumber,
    T.[Level],
    T.PartNumber,
    T.ProductNumber,
    COALESCE(CTE.[Key], T.[Key]) AS [Key]
FROM source_table T
LEFT JOIN cte_recursion CTE
  ON T.RowNumber = CTE.RowNumber
ORDER BY T.RowNumber;


This doesn't produce the outcome desired by the OP specifically rows 5 nd 6.
